# Bound for type of correlation measure

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, it.information-theory, norms

Assume you have a finite, discrete probability distribution for a joint random variable and such that $P(X=i,Y=j) = p_{i,j}$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, |X|\},j \in \{1, \dots, |Y|\}$.  The marginal distributions are given by $Prob(X=i) = p_i = \sum_{j=1}^{|Y|} p_{i,j}$ and similarly $Prob(Y=j) = q_j = \sum_{i=1}^{|X|} p_{i,j}$ for the other marginal.

**I would like to get a "good" upper bound in terms of the mutual information for the following expression:**
$$
\sum_{i,j} (p_{i,j} - p_i q_j) \log(p_i) \log(q_j).
$$

Now, I can do
$$
\sum_{i,j} (p_{i,j} - p_i q_j) \log(p_i) \log(q_j)\\
\leq |\sum_{i,j} (p_{i,j} - p_i q_j) \log(p_i) \log(q_j)| \\
\leq \sum_{i,j} | p_{i,j} - p_i q_j|| \log(p_i)|| \log(q_j)| \\
\leq \sum_{i,j} | p_{i,j} - p_i q_j |\max_{i,j}|\log(p_i)|| \log(q_j)| \\
= ||P_{XY} - P_{X}P_{Y}||_1|\log( \min_i p_i)|| \log( \min_j q_j)| \\
\leq \sqrt{2I(X:Y)}|\log( \min_i p_i)|| \log( \min_j q_j)|
$$
where $I(X:Y)$ denotes the mutual information and where I used the triangle inequality and Pinsker's inequality. Note that I can assume without loss of generality that $p_{i},q_j > 0$ for all $i,j$ since zero terms simply disappear from the original sum (taking $0\log0=0$).

However, this bound is not good enough for my purposes. I need a bound that cannot be made arbitrarily large simply by decreasing the smallest (non-positive) marginal probability. **Instead, I'm looking for a bound of the form $M\sqrt{I(X:Y)}\log(|X|)\log(|Y|)$ for some $M \in \mathbb{N}$.**

Comment: Numerical experiments indicate that a bound of the form $\sqrt{I(X:Y)}\log(|X|\cdot|Y|)$ might be plausible. Would that be good enough?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich, thanks. The kind of community I'm addressing would expect an analytical derivation I'm afraid. The crucial difficulty I think is that one has to make explicit use of the relationship between p_{ij} and the marginals, since the above bound for generic random probability vectors does not hold.

Comment: Of course we'd want a rigorous proof! I was asking if the bound of the type I proposed is sufficiently good for your purposes. What motivates this question, btw?

Comment: It's definitely false if your replace $\sqrt{I(X:Y)}$ by $I(X:Y)$ -- I can provide easy examples.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich, sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, the bound from your first comment would be good enough.

Comment: Regarding motivation, I work in quantum information theory (i.e. coming from physics). I'm trying to establish a statement that forbids the existence of stochastic processes on a bipartite system (modelled as an unital map on a joint random variable) that "compress" the information on both subsystems simultaneously, without also increasing their entropy. I already have such a statement, however, I could make a much stronger statement if the above was true. It's probably not very clear what I mean here, I'm struggling to give a motivation that is both precise and short.

Comment: I kicked it around for a few hours and couldn't get it. Let's see if someone on here is able to solve it. If not, feel free to get in touch with me off-line -- could be an interesting research project, if properly motivated.

Comment: Let me revise my numerical bound to $O(\sqrt{I(X:Y)}\log(|X|)\log(|Y|))$. Is that still good enough?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich, yes, that bound would still be good enough, I edited the question accordingly. Thanks for taking the time. I, in the meanwhile, tried to solve the case $|X|=|Y|=2$, however without success so far.

Comment: In fact, it would be sufficient to bound the expression **without the vertical bars** from above, i.e. not the absolute value. This could be much simpler.

Comment: @MattF., yes, I edited that. It seemed clear enough what I mean, but just in case...

Comment: I think you've already solved the $|X|=|Y|=2$ case via Pinsker's inequality in your OP; the constant is hidden in O(.).

Comment: ok, I guess I might have been misusing Big O notation then since I actually _am_ concerned with the behaviour of the expression for all alphabet sizes. But apart from the question of alphabet size, I'm not sure I understand your last comment: The bound I give in the OP, already in the case of binary alphabets, does not yield a constant $M$ such that, for all joint distributions, the expression is upper bounded by $M\sqrt{I}\log(2)^2$, no? So which constant are you referring to?

Comment: I take that back. The binary case is still nontrivial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89527/discussion-between-aryeh-kontorovich-and-paul).

Answer (score 2):

Let $V := \sum_{ij}(p_{ij}-p_{i}q_{j})\ln p_{i}\ln q_{j}$ indicate your quantity of interest. Then,
\begin{align}
V &\le \sum_{ij}\left|p_{ij}-p_{i}q_{j}\right|\left|\ln p_{i}\ln q_{j}\right|\\
& = \sum_{ij}\frac{\left|p_{ij}-p_{i}q_{j}\right|}{\sqrt{p_{ij} + p_iq_i}}\left|\sqrt{p_{ij} + p_iq_i} \ln p_{i} \ln q_{j}\right| \\
& \le \sqrt{\sum_{ij}\frac{(p_{ij}-p_{i}q_{j})^2}{p_{ij}+p_iq_i}}\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} (p_{ij}+p_iq_i) \ln^2 p_{i} \ln^2 q_{j}} \tag{1}
\end{align}
where the last line uses Cauchy-Schwartz. 
The sum inside the first square root in Eq. 1 is called *triangular discrimination* between $p_{XY}$ and $p_X p_Y$, and can be bound as
\begin{align}
\Delta(p_{XY} \Vert p_X p_Y) = \sum_{ij} \frac{(p_{ij} - p_iq_j)^2}{p_{ij} + p_iq_j} \le \frac{32}{27} D_\mathrm{KL}(p_{XY} \Vert p_X p_Y)  = \frac{32}{27} I(X:Y) \tag{2}
\end{align}
(see Tenaja, "Bounds On Triangular Discrimination, Harmonic Mean and Symmetric Chi-square Divergences", [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505238.pdf), Eq. 4.38 for the inequality).

We now upper bound the sum inside the second square root. Note that $p_{ij} \le p_i$ and $p_{ij} \le q_j$, so $p_{ij} \le \sqrt{p_i}\sqrt{q_j}$. This gives
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i,j} (p_{ij}+p_iq_i) \ln^2 p_{i} \ln^2 q_{j}\\
\le &  \sum_{i,j} (\sqrt{p_i}\sqrt{q_i}+p_iq_i) \ln^2 p_{i} \ln^2 q_{j} \\
=& \Big(\sum_{i} \sqrt{p_i} \ln^2 p_{i} \Big)\Big(\sum_{j} \sqrt{q_j} \ln^2 q_{j} \Big) + \Big(\sum_{i} {p_i} \ln^2 p_{i} \Big)\Big(\sum_{j} {q_j} \ln^2 q_{j} \Big) \\
\le & |X||Y|\frac{16^2 + 4^2}{e^4} \tag{3}
\end{align}
where we use $\max_{x \in [0,1]} \sqrt{x} \ln^2 x = 16/e^2$ and $\max_{x \in [0,1]} x \ln^2 x = 4/e^2$ (e.g. can be found using Mathematica).

Combining Eqs. 1-3 gives
\begin{align}
V \le C \sqrt{|X|}\sqrt{|Y|} \sqrt{I(X:Y)}
\end{align}
where
$$
C = \sqrt{\frac{32}{27}}\frac{\sqrt{272}}{e^2} \approx 2.43
$$

**P.S.** I realized that your question asks for a bound of the type $C \log{|X|}\log{|Y|} \sqrt{I(X:Y)}$, not $C \sqrt{|X|}\sqrt{|Y|} \sqrt{I(X:Y)}$. Not sure whether this can be derived.

Comment: Hey Artemy, thanks a lot for your answer (and sorry about the late reply). That's a very nice trick, to split into two square roots, thereby making cauchy schwarz work good enough. I also don't know how to improve on the bound on the second term to yield the calsing that I originally asked for, but in fact, your result is good enough for the purpose of my paper

Comment: So, in terms of the MathOverflow rules, since you don't answer my original question but do solve the problem sufficiently well for me, does this mean I should accept your reply as an answer or not? I could wait another week or so, and then accept.

Comment: Also, if this result does end up in the paper, I would like to acknowledge you. If you're interested in this, I could either acknowledge your Stack-Overflow account or the real "you". If you prefer the latter, feel free to drop me a message in chat. I'd acknowledge mathoverflow and this thread in either case.

Comment: Great. Yes I would prefer to be acknowledged. Sorry I am not too familiar with the chat system, if it's OK with you I will send you an email.